# Why are most of my Pre-Installed apps that connect to Google not working?

Tags: google-play-store, google, google-play-services

Okay, I am using a Huawei m865c (Ascend II), running Android 2.3.6.

I am trying to open Google Play, but it tells me that there is no connection. I am connected to a 20 mb/ps with all bars. I tried connecting another account, but it would load for 5 minutes and tell me that my phone has no connection or isn't provisioned for data services (duh, that's why I have WiFi). Help! I've tried everything in my book to fix it, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Do Gmail, etc. give the exact same error that Play does?

Comment: Actually, they don't even give me an error code. When I try to connect to Google play, it says "No Connection" and gives me an option to try again, which ultimately leads me back to the error screen.When I try to downgrade my Google Play Store back to the Android Market, the old version gives me the same thing. It does the same thing as well with Google Talk (or Hangouts, whatever floats your boat). The only Google products that work on my phone are Gmail Voice Search, and Maps.

Comment: We're getting tons of questions about this sort of issue at the moment, across lots of devices and Android versions.  I wonder if Google is having server issues.